# Java - save Internet Radio stream

Tags: java, audio, stream, audio-recording

i want to record a internet radio show that is running during midday, where i cann´t listen to it.

The URL of the radio is:
http://radio.orf.at/player/radioplayer.html?station=ooe

I looked at the DOM to find out where the player gets its data from.
I believe that it is this server:
"http://194.232.200.148:8000"

When i type this in my browser a documents appears which grows over the time, so i assume its the data of the stream.

As I read in the DOM the data is in the audio/mpeg format, so i thought i could write a little program that grabs the data and just saves it as a *.mpeg file.

My test program looks like:

```
URL u = new URL("http://194.232.200.148:8000");
            InputStream openStream = u.openStream();
            long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            BufferedWriter bw = null;

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\Lukas\\Desktop\\test.mpeg"));
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            while (true) {
                int read = openStream.read();

                System.out.println(read);
                if (read == -1 || curTime + 60000 < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                    break;
                }
                bw.write(read);
                bw.flush();

            }
            bw.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

But as i already feared, it seems that it´s is not that easy.

I get the data to the file, but it´s not an valid .mpeg file.

So i wanted to ask if anyone has experience with this kind of issues and can help me solve the problem or atleast give me a hint what to do.

yours, Lukas

Answer (score 0):

MPEG files have headers, without those a player won't read them.  Also you have to be sure what the actual format is, it might be some copy protected format that you can't just simply create a header for and play in a normal player.  Maybe lookup the MPEG file format structure as a start.